# Has "Auto eth0" been renamed to "Automatic ethernet"?

Tags: 11.04, networking

Today when I checked my network settings I saw that there in addition to the connection "Auto eth0" was the connection "Automatic Ethernet" (and I haven't added it myself nor done any changes to the network configuration). The only difference is that the latter has no assigned MAC address. Is this a sign of some new change to the network manager? Or what is it?

Comment: I know this has been changed in 11.10 (Beta), so maybe it has been pushed into 11.04 with an update :p

Comment: @RobinJ are you sure? Because I'm running 11.10 and I have auto eth0.

Comment: That's strange... Well, on the Live CD it said "Automatic ethernet".

Comment: I believe the default names have changed ; my ethernet is now "Wired connection 1" rather than "auto eth0" ; but I think it's just the name it allocates on creation, which explains why Roland's still says "auto eth0" if he's upgrading.

Comment: @Adrian I have two network cards and they're named "Wired connection 1" and "Wired connection 2" on a fresh install. You should write an answer based on this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this would appear to be "yes".

The default name patterns for network adapters in Network Manager have been changed. I believe that upgraded installations will keep their existing adapter names.

Citation (idea marked as being in development March 2011) :

http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/27250/

GNOME master bug (marked as fixed)

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=587844